# Calculate the average number of hours in table per month

Tags: mysql

I have a table named "loginhistory", and I need to calculate the most active hour of the month. How can i do it?

My table structure is:
id, userId, date (datetime), ip.

I tried to do it in PHP but I did not succeed there either. I prefer the calculation to be done only in MySql.

I expect the output to be just the number of the most active hour.

Comment: Read the mysql documentation for `hour()`, `count()` and `max()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter checking average number if needed to pick active hour.

Cause `average = count / days` and since `days` is the same for whole calculation (let's say `30`) the greatest `count` will be active hour in list.

Just select by date range and group by hour and pick 1st one from descending sort:

```
SELECT 
  HOUR(date) AS hour,
  COUNT(id) AS logins,
  ( COUNT(id) / DAY(LAST_DAY('2019-01-01')) ) AS logins_avg
FROM loginhistory
WHERE 
  date >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND date < '2019-02-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY HOUR(date)
ORDER BY logins DESC LIMIT 1
```